# Permission Issue with unlink

Tags: php, permissions, unlink

I'm on linux and I'm trying to delete a file. But, I continue to receive permission errors. I've tried using both `chown` and `chmod` and setting both to 666, 777 and 0777, and unlink($file, 0777) with no success. Is there something I'm missing?

```
        $path = scandir('../folder1/folder2');

        $file = realpath('../folder1/folder2/'.$path[2]);
        //chown($file, 0777);
        //chmod($file, 0777);

        if (!unlink($file)))
        {
             echo ("Error deleting $path[2]");
        }
        else
        {
            echo ("Deleted $path[2]");
         }
```

Comment: Are the permissions changed to 777? Can you sudo chmod on the server?

Comment: Not sure actually, how would I check?

Comment: Are you ftped or command line? FTP should have an option for "file permissions". Command line `ls -l`, when located in the particular directory.

Comment: Ok I went to the terminal and executed chmod 777 on the file executing the unlink statement. It executed fine and changed the file permissions but I'm still getting the permission error message.